# Nginx and enabling CORS

Tags: nginx, cors, vagrant

NGINX config doesn't enable CORS

I've searched all day on how to enable the cross requests and so far I got nothing, I have an angular app serving on 127.0.0.1:3081/3080 and I want it to make CORS requests to an API which is running currently on a vagrant virtual machine running nginx 1.11.

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name harzreisen.test;
root "/home/vagrant/Code/harzreisen2/harzreisen-server/api";

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/harzreisen.test-error.log error;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location / {

  dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;

  # Preflighted requestis
  if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE";
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    return 200;
  }

  # CORS WHITELIST EVERYTHING
  # This is allowing everything because I am running
  # locally so there should be no security issues.
  if ($request_method = (GET|POST|OPTIONS|HEAD|DELETE)) {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
  }

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
}
```

It just the website doesnt reach the POST request, it gives me 200 on OPTIONS and thats it.. Can someone explain me whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `more_set_headers` on nginx.conf instead of `add_header`; following your example:

```
    more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
    more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, DELETE";
    more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    (...)
```

The *more_set_headers* directive is part of the [HttpHeadersMore](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module which is included in the [nginx-extras flavor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/553937/what-is-the-difference-between-the-core-full-extras-and-light-packages-for-ngi#556382) of nginx, you can install it on ubuntu 16 by doing:

> sudo apt-get install nginx-extras